# Получение ссылки для скачивания на файл из телеграмма, без скачивания себе на компьютер

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Я использую библиотеку pyrogram и появилась необходимость передачи прямой ссылки на скачивание файла из чата, без скачивание этого файла к себе на компьютер. Покопался в интернете, но ничего подходящего не нашел. Полез в саму библиотеку и нашел метод handle_download в классе Client, вроде из него можно достать нужный функционал, но я новичок в этом всём и не смог понять, что там происходит в целом.

Чтобы может было понятнее, мне нужно получить прямую ссылку на файл, чтобы передать её в допустим метод апи яндекс диска upload_url и не приходилось скачивать этот файл на компьютер в виде файла или bytesIO в памяти.

Можно ли это вообще сделать для больших файлов и без сложных операций?

Заранее спасибо за любой ответ!